# Sequel: Where are folder icons kept and what is the mechanism? OS: XP SP2

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, icons

A few weeks ago I asked [Where are the folder icons generated with the folder properties kept in the Registry?](https://superuser.com/questions/683180/where-are-the-folder-icons-generated-with-the-folder-properties-kept-in-the-regi) and received some useful answers (from Nixda and Scott). Since then I've found that there must be another way of setting a folder icon other than by using a desktop.ini file. The mechanism is used by the PowerDesk file manager (I used version 6). It offers a "Change Folder Icon" option in its file menu.

This allows you to choose from a limited number of alternative icons without the use of a desktop.ini. Indeed, if you subsequently insert a desktop.ini for a different icon, it will override the Powerdesk icon. Delete the desktop.ini, and the Powerdesk icon reappears. It seems therefore that Powerdesk modifies the registry.

Comment: Check the associated registry entries before and after and determine how (and if) PowerDesk is modifying it. I believe I heard of registry compare utilities that would make it easier to do this.

Comment: There's mention of some registry analysis utilities in the answers to the question [_How to log and compare Windows Registry data before and after any program installation?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911689/how-to-log-and-compare-windows-registry-data-before-and-after-any-program-instal).

Comment: I used "WhatChanged" on three occasions, each time with a different result and none of them very meaningful. I'll have to try again tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't been able to find where these data are kept but the question has become slightly academic as I have found a program (IconChanger from Shell Labs) which inserts the data. I'd still be interested to know where, though. IconChanger will not only assign an icon to a folder without resorting to a desktop.ini, but it will also assign an icon to an **individual** file, no matter what extension.